# How to separate the Positive and negative record from a query which is calculate the all balance sum......?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select account
     , SUM(balance) as bal
from Main_report
Group BY account
```

How can I separate the positive and negative records from the above query?
I want to combine this query with the cases listed below.

```
select (case when bal < 0 then bal else 0 end) as debits,
(case when bal > 0 then bal else 0 end) as credits from Main_report
Group BY account
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use your two cases and sum the result of those:

```
SELECT account
     , SUM(CASE WHEN balance < 0 THEN balance ELSE 0 END) as debits
     , SUM(CASE WHEN balance > 0 THEN balance ELSE 0 END) as credits
FROM Main_report
GROUP BY account
```

Comment: i want to apply that cases on the result which is calculated by the upper query

Comment: @UmairAhmad: That's not possible, at least not how the query is written now. `SUM` is an aggregate function, it adds together anything you throw at it, no matter if it is a positive number (>0) or a negative number (<0). What you could do is using two seperate queries with the `WHERE` clause only querying negative balances in the first and only positive balances in the second query.

Comment: if  query return a results of Sum(balances ) i want to separate that results of balances positive records are in positive field and negative value is in negative field

Comment: @UmairAhmad: I'm afraid I don't quite understand. Seems to me like this might be a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: select account
     , SUM(balance) as bal this will calculate the Sum of balance i want to apply that cases on the output of this Query